# Prevent padding from increasing size

Tags: css, padding

Here's a sample:

```css
div {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 12px;
  background: tan;
}
```

```html
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
```

Is there a way to prevent padding from increasing the size of the `div`? Some threads suggest using `box-sizing: border-box`, but it doesn't seem to work in this case.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You have set `height: 0;`. Padding is set at the inside of the target which will increase the dimention of the div. Whats the required output?

Comment: @Nitheesh: When I programmatically give the desired height to the `div`, it will have a padding.

Comment: If you are setting the height programatically, remove the padding. Why are you add padding then, adding padding to div will increase its physical height

Comment: Are you maybe observing the background? Does `background-clip: content-box;` hit on what you're after? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip

Comment: @Nitheesh: Actually I’m looking for a padding replacement/alternative: something that increases the space between the border and content. Consider the following [scenario](https://codepen.io/Mike-MC/pen/ExwEaWL). I can't seem to add padding programmatically. It needs to be already there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace it with margin by adding an extra div

```css
div.box {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: tan;
}

div.box div {
  margin: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
</div>
```

Or consider some hack with pseudo element:

```css
div.box {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: tan;
  padding: 0 15px; /* horizontal padding */
}

div.box:before,
div.box:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 12px; /* vertical padding */
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without an extra element?

Comment: @Mike check the update

Comment: @Mike it's not needed in the second one, I forget to remove it

Answer (score 0):

If you are there for extra space, you can use {margin} instead which will only add space outside of the ““ box. Also if you want spacing between the text, you can use css property {line-height}.